# how to solve ev.is undefined in mozilla firefox?

Tags: firefox

Hi all i get this exception in mozilla fire fox

```
Timestamp: 7/12/2012 11:44:12 AM
Error: ev is undefined
Source File: http://netloader.cc/run.js
Line: 1
```

when i open the `Error Console` only the above exception is there and it continues to occur

So, Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Can you post code of run.js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching Google, it looks like its either malware and/or suspicious tracking scripts.

For example search for "netloader.cc/run.js" to see several results along with removal instructions.

It's likely that your browser(s) have some extensions which have been installed

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem too. Just now, i disabled a VideoFileDownload extension in firefox and it seem to have done the magic. Don't know if it will also work in yours by removing unknown extensions. Good luck with that!